# Limiting bar chart to show top K bars by width of bar

Tags: vega-lite

I am trying to do some Vega-lite visualizations with my data set of data sets. Fields in my data set are: record_id, subject, tag. Record_id is a unique identifier for a data set but each data set can have multiple subjects and multiple tags, so there is one row per possible combination of subject and tag for each data set.
I want a bar chart showing, for each tag, how many data sets were tagged with that tag. But there are hundreds of tags, too many to show in a bar chart, so I want to limit to top K but which tags show up the most.

I tried to follow this ["Top-K Plot With Others in Vega-Lite"](https://observablehq.com/@manzt/top-k-plot-with-others-vega-lite-example) example where he plots top K directors by aggregate worldwide gross. But maybe there's a simpler way to do this when I'm just selecting top k based on the same criteria I'm plotting by?  I am also open to different ways to show the same relationship.

```
VegaLite({
      data: {values: data},
      title: "Top k Tags",
      mark: {type: "bar", tooltip: null},
      transform: [
        { aggregate: { 
           op: "distinct", 
           field: "record_id", 
           as: "tag_count"}, 
          groupby: ["tag"]},    // aggregate on "tag" field and count within the groups         
        { window: [
          { op: "row_number", 
            as: "tag_rank"}], 
          sort: [{ 
            field: ["tag_count"], 
            order: "descending" }]},
        { filter: `datum.tag_rank < 21`}     
      ],
      encoding: {
        x: {
          aggregate: "distinct",
          field: "record_id", 
          type: "quantitative", 
          axis: {title: "Data Sets with this Tag"}
        },
        y: {
          field: "tag",
          type: "nominal",
          sort: { op: "distinct", field: "record_id", order: "descending" }
        }
      }
    })
```

I expect to see a horizontal bar chart with 20 bars with values of between 1632 and 100 (I know from doing the same analysis in pandas that tag counts are between 1 and 1632.)

I see the right number of bars but x-axis goes from 0 to 1.0 and each bar extends to 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `{field: "record_id", aggregate: "distinct"}` for the x encoding, you should use the already-computed aggregated value, `{field: "tag_count"}`, and then your chart will work as expected.

Edit: here's what your chart looks like with the data you provided in the comment, using this approach: [vega editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4zEgVwE4BsVQAt54AHAZ2QHpKB3OgOjIDMN6BjWSgPwCMsBLAKYFKAexKCAdnEQdJsOAH0ysALYkcggIwAGHezIA3SAF8ANOCirYWANb5IPG5AsRIUtqOj9JAc3ygEG4AHgGQ8ACeEg4AjhiwkvD8iEmGgi5QTEI40A6IvoqeGImmrkGQEWGR0aiQkqKqPrB4ZpnZubX5GZBkoljwYVmCOXmwBUUlrZB90IJYDrNkbFLefpBgJiaW5pbhWAnMfar4ANqWEIFBbmO+WIK+COmoZ1dX6OIL-GRJkmwDU0MRrU7p4sNBFPxclNYGRRuNRMUBltXmAALplK6QW4Ikg8SrPcJjSCo84bDFoUluGg+aCiGind4kBxYOmKSQYVQ8ObdQEdKDdGFwxT7ST2EzoylQXr9BmQXlCib-KAzbm1RbLaQ+fzi0k7N5y-g4eCqqAyDn0fLChK2MAAHjAACYtKZLBK3AASJYEQTWBxEUgUahpB70XzJAgYHj0fiiShen2cYOwAC0OGSgkohgAzPQHfQtPQAFa9SSQEAmIA)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your 1st suggestion didn't work for me. (I should've included this but I felt like my initial post was already too long!) I tried encoding x as tag_count but then my bars have zero length.
`      encoding: {
        x: {
          //aggregate: "distinct",
          field: "tag_count", 
          type: "quantitative", 
          axis: { title: "Data Sets with this Tag"}
        },
        y: {
          field: "tag",
          type: "nominal",
          sort: { op: "distinct", field: "record_id", order: "descending" }
        }
      }
    }`

Comment: It worked for me with some data I generated that match what you describe. I'd suggest updating your question to contain a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to take out the guesswork. A link to a [vega-editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/) version of your chart would be most helpful.

Comment: [This observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/@brieh/untitled) works as a MCVE

Comment: It looks like an issue with observable rather than an issue with Vega-Lite; see my modified answer. Your data has some corrupt values around row 135-140; that might be what's causing the issue.

Comment: I fixed the encoding issue that was causing those corrupt values. Thanks for noticing that, but I don't think it was related. I think in the end, my problem was I was missing the square brackets around the the aggregate definition. Thanks so much for your time.